# Plotly / Dash: how to force clipping at the margins of a bubble plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash

Take the following sample code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4], y=[10, 11, 12, 13],
    text=['A<br>size: 40', 'B<br>size: 60', 'C<br>size: 80', 'D<br>size: 100'],
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        color=['rgb(93, 164, 214)', 'rgb(255, 144, 14)',  'rgb(44, 160, 101)', 'rgb(255, 65, 54)'],
        size=[40, 60, 80, 100],
    )
)])

fig.show()
```

which outputs...

[image]

When changing the red bubble size to `300`, we get...

[image]

As you can see, both x and y axes have been rescaled to accommodate the new marker size.

However, I'd need the axes to remain unchanged, and despite the marker size having increased it should be clipped.

This is necessary as my project entails turning on and off bubbles over another plot (via callback), and when bubbles are turned on, the chart is changing in width.

Any ideas how to accomplish a static x and y axes and have the markers clipped regardless of size?

`cliponaxis=True` does not seem to produce the desired result.

Below is an example of the desired clipping:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by fixing the axes range.

import plotly.graph_objects as go

```
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4], y=[10, 11, 12, 13],
    text=['A<br>size: 40', 'B<br>size: 60', 'C<br>size: 80', 'D<br>size: 100'],
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        color=['rgb(93, 164, 214)', 'rgb(255, 144, 14)', 'rgb(44, 160, 101)', 'rgb(255, 65, 54)'],
        size=[40, 60, 80, 500],
    ), cliponaxis=True
)])
fig.update_yaxes(range=[10, 13])
fig.update_xaxes(range=[1, 4])

fig.show()
```

[image]